# Assignment like String

Tags: java

I recently went for a Java Interview where the interviewer asked me a question I could not answer. He asked me how I'd create a class whose instances can be assigned to a String, just like a string. Allow me to explain:

Say I create a class, MyClass and I create an object of it, say obj. The assignment should be such that:

```
MyClass obj = "my Text";
```

I searched for this sort of thing but could not get any precise answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say "assigned to a String" but your code example shows being assigned a `String` value. These are very different things. The former is easy: just write a `toString()` method in `MyClass`. The latter is basically impossible since `String` is a final class.

More technically with respect to the last point: If you look at the [rules for assignment conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.2), a `String` value can only be assigned to a variable of type `String` or some wider reference type. The only wider reference types are `Object`, `CharSequence`, `Serializable`, and `Comparable<String>`. (Tip of the hat to Stephen C).

Comment: Yes, I suspect this is what they meant, though you're not really "assigning the instance to a String" in a technical sense (partly because that makes no technical sense...).

Comment: *"The only wider reference type is Object."* - or `CharSequence`, `Comparable<String>` or `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want to do is possible.

The expression `"my Text"` is equivalent to `new String("my Text")` so in effect what you you're trying to do is:

```
MyClass obj = new String("my Text");
```

So `MyClass` would have to be a subclass of `java.lang.String` but `String` is declared as `final` which means subclassing is expressly forbidden.

Comment: _"my Text" is equivalent to new String("my Text")_ -- not exactly. The compile-time constant `"my Text"` will be interned, whereas the String expression `new String("my Text")` will not be an interned string.